# Data is not refreshing after delete query with RTK Query

Tags: javascript, rtk-query

I am using RTK Query and I have problems with refreshing component after I made changes in data. I am trying to remove item from cart which is working. The problem is that I need to refresh page every time I click on a button that is calling `handleRemoveFromCart` because elements displayed on that page are not refreshing. I have been trying to mount again component with useEffect but with no effect. I'm working first time with RTK Query and I would be grateful for help.

Here is my cartSlice.js

```
import { createSelector, createEntityAdapter } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { apiSlice } from './apiSlice';

const cartAdapter = createEntityAdapter();

const initialState = cartAdapter.getInitialState();

export const cartApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCart: builder.query({
      query: () => '/cart',
      transformResponse: (responseData) => {
        return cartAdapter.setAll(initialState, responseData);
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, arg) => [
        { type: 'Cart', id: 'LIST' },
        ...result.ids.map((id) => ({ type: 'Cart', id: 'LIST' })),
      ],
    }),
    addCartItem: builder.mutation({
      query: (initialProduct) => ({
        url: '/cart',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          ...initialProduct,
        },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: [{ type: 'Cart', id: 'LIST' }],
    }),
    deleteCartItem: builder.mutation({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `/cart/${id}`,
        method: 'DELETE',
        invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [{ type: 'Cart', id: arg.id }],
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

And the Cart component

```
const CartPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector(selectAllCart);
  const [deleteCartItem] = useDeleteCartItemMutation(
    {},
    { refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true },
  );
  const [shippingValue, setShippingValue] = useState(0);

  const getTotal = () => {
    let totalQuantity = 0;
    let totalPrice = 0;
    cart.forEach((cart) => {
      totalQuantity += cart.item.quantity;
      totalPrice += cart.item.price * cart.quantity;
    });
    return { totalPrice, totalQuantity };
  };

  const handleRemoveFromCart = async (id) => {
    try {
      await deleteCartItem(id).unwrap();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

When you delete an item you need to invalidate both that item and the `LIST`.  Right now it is not refreshing because you have not invalidated the `LIST`.

```
invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [
  { type: 'Cart', id: 'LIST' },
  { type: 'Cart', id: arg.id }
],
```

You also have a mistake in your `getCart` query.  You should be using the actual `id` when you map.

```
providesTags: (result, error, arg) => [
  { type: 'Cart', id: 'LIST' },
   ...result.ids.map((id) => ({ type: 'Cart', id })),
],
```

---

There is a simpler way of dealing with tag invalidation which would probably work just as well here.  Rather than invalidating individual items in the cart, you can invalidate the entire cart as a whole.

```
export const cartApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCart: builder.query({
      query: () => '/cart',
      providesTags: ['Cart'],
    }),
    addCartItem: builder.mutation({
      query: (initialProduct) => ({
        url: '/cart',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          ...initialProduct,
        },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Cart'],
    }),
    deleteCartItem: builder.mutation({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `/cart/${id}`,
        method: 'DELETE',
        invalidatesTags: ['Cart'],
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. The problem is that after I click a button that handle delete function my cart is not refreshing the list of items that are on the page. I have to manualy refresh page to refresh list of items in cart.

Comment: Ok I'm looking at your component now and it seems like you are copying the data from the cart to somewhere else in your state.  You don't need to do that.  You should access it directly from the RTK query hook.  `const { data, isLoading } = useGetCartQuery(); const cart = data;`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not changing anything. I still have same issue which is not refreshing list of items. After i use `handleRemoveFromCart` my `console.log(data)` is not showing anything so for me it kidna looks like redux state is not refreshing after that operation? Or maybe component on itself neet to mount again somehow?

Here is a link for this github repo if needed https://github.com/Jacob120/e-commerce-fullstack-app

Answer (score -1):

Looks like by adding this lines it started to finally work like it should. With adding to handleRemove setRefresh(true) and on useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(refetch);
    setRefresh(false);
  }, [refresh, dispatch]);
```

Comment: Why call dispatch within the useEffect hook? I bet this does not work. useEffect hook, by default, executes after:

the initial render
each time a component is re-rendered